# pip install - requirements.txt error

Tags: pip, installation

```
Naiches-Mini:instabot.py-master NEEcH$ pip install -r requirements.txt

Collecting requests==2.12.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

Using cached requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Installing collected packages: requests

Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main status = self.run(options, args)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run prefix=options.prefix_path,

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install **kwargs

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files isolated=self.isolated,

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber ensure_dir(destdir)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/init.py", line 83, in ensure_dir os.makedirs(path)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs mkdir(name, mode)

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests'

Naiches-Mini:instabot.py-master NEEcH$
```

Comment: Please add some text explaining what you're trying to do, what's wrong and so on. Not just a copy/paste of your error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see there are [Errno 13] Permission denied; which means permission is require; so

> sudo pip install -r requirements.txt

is going to give it the permission.
I have got the same error with python installed by pythonorg in MacOS.